# How to blurr all images except the current hover via css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there  a pure css method to blur all images except the one being hovered on? My current code is shown in the following link. I have a wrap to blur the area but Just cannot get the image being hovered over to not blur!

Thanks!

Basic concept:

```
.wrap:hover
   {
   -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
    -moz-filter: blur(13px);
    -o-filter: blur(13px);
    -ms-filter: blur(13px);
    filter: blur(13px);  

}

img:hover
{
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
-moz-filter: blur(0px);
-o-filter: blur(0px);
-ms-filter: blur(0px);
filter: blur(0px);  

}
```

Full code found at

https://jsfiddle.net/0q00jorc/2/
* edit

Basically, I was trying to blurr all images except the exact one I was hovering over and not blur anything if I am not on the images. The code from the answer below did just that except it blurred all the images if I was hovering over the wrap which includes spaces in between images. I do not want to blurr unless I am on the images themselves.

Comment: Does this mean that you want everything to be blurred by default? e.g. if the cursor is not in the window

Comment: the way I read it, he want a spot-light like  feature, that is: everything else on the collection gets blurred except the element of interest  under the mouse hover. Because the opposite i.e.: having all images blurred initially and then sharpen only the one hovered upon, is elementary.

Comment: So yea, I am trying to blur all images except the one the mouse is hovering on  only when I hover over an image. Not blurr all by default. The solution below works great but it blurs everything even when not hovering over the specific image.

Answer (score 4):

Put the blur effect on the images, then have an img hover that overrides the blur.

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #EEE;
   font: 10px/13px 'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
}
.box {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 20%;
   padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.boxInner {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
  outline: 15px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline-offset: -15px;
}
.boxInner .titleBox {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   background: #000;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrap:hover img
{
   -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
    -moz-filter: blur(13px);
    -o-filter: blur(13px);
    -ms-filter: blur(13px);
    filter: blur(13px);  
  
}

.wrap:hover img:hover
{
   -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);  
}
}

body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    
  <!-- Define all of the tiles: -->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/7.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Butterfly</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">An old greenhouse</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/2.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Purple wildflowers</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/3.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">A birdfeeder</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/10.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Crocus close-up</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/4.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">The garden shop</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/5.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Spring daffodils</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/6.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Iris along the path</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/8.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">The garden blueprint</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/9.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">The patio</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/11.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Bumble bee collecting nectar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/12.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Winding garden path</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is it. You sir are a genius!! The only strange thing is if you hover in between the cracks then all the images are blurred.  Also, going on the edge (wrap) also still blurs everything. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, I was trying to blurr all images except the exact one I was hovering over and not blur anything if I am not on the images. Yours code did just that except it blurred all the images if I was hovering over the wrap which includes spaces in between images. Anyway you could point me in the right direction how to do this? I tried to change your .wrap: hover to boxinner but it doesnt do anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
 -webkit-filter: blur(13px);
 -moz-filter: blur(13px);
 -o-filter: blur(13px);
 -ms-filter: blur(13px);
 filter: blur(13px);
}   

img:hover {
 -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
 -moz-filter: blur(0px);
 -o-filter: blur(0px);
 -ms-filter: blur(0px);
 filter: blur(0px);
}
```